# SQL insert and update data into column based on other Table column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, sql-update

I have two tables:
table PRODUCTS

```
| ProductID | ProductPrice  | ProductSupplier |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| 1         |    25         | CompanyA        |
| 2         |    35         | CompanyB        |
| 3         |    12         | CompanyC        |
```

table SUPPLIERS

| SupplierID | SupplierName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CompanyA |
| 2 | CompanyB |
| 3 | CompanyC |

How to insert new column SupplierID into table Products, based on values from table Suppliers but with corresponding values from column ProductSupplier?
example of new desired output:
Table PRODUCTS

```
    | ProductID | ProductPrice  | ProductSupplier | SupplierID |
    +-----------+---------------+-----------------+------------+
    | 1         |    25         | CompanyA        | ID value from table Suppliers |
    | 2         |    35         | CompanyB        | ID value from table Suppliers |
    | 3         |    12         | CompanyC        | ID value from table Suppliers |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an update join:

```sql
UPDATE PRODUCTS p
INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS s
    ON s.SupplierName = p.ProductSupplier
SET p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID;
```

Note that you are moving in the direction of more normalization, which is a good thing.  Assuming you are intending to keep the `SUPPLIER` table, then the `ProductSupplier` column in the `PRODUCTS` table is now redundant and can probably be dropped:

```sql
ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS DROP COLUMN ProductSupplier;
```

Comment: I would like to keep ProductSupplier column in PRODUCTS table. It has recorded values.
I need to insert SupplierID in PRODUCTS table, so i can use a lookup table to fill values automatically.